# How can I get a combinations of a string in a row (range)?

Tags: java, google-apps-script

For example, in row A2:C2, the values are a2,b2,c2 respectively,
I want the result(concatenated):
a2b2c2
a2c2b2
b2a2c2
b2a2c2
c2a2b2
c2b2a2

Comment: There is no function in Google Sheets to achieve what you want. Have you considered using Apps Script?

Comment: Do you want to format the values in 3 cells into the list of combinations, or compute and output the combinations? I wonder the former once can be performed by formula

Answer (score 2):

The permutations can be generated using the [Factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system)<sup>1</sup> together with [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code)<sup>1</sup> (actually decoding).

There are `n!` permutations, if `n` is the number of elements. For each number from `0` up to `n!-1`, the algorithm calculates its representation in the factorial base and then decode this as a Lehmer code, which will give the index to be used for each position. Basically this calculates every possible value for each position, excluding values from previous positions - *inspired* by [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) on Wikipedia.

Here an example in Java: <sub>(since question is marked with that tag)</sub>

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Permutation {

    private final int len;
    private final String[] values;
    private final int[] factorials;
    private final int count;

    public Permutation(String... values) {
        this.len = values.length;
        this.values = values;
        this.factorials = new int[len];
        var fact = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            factorials[i] = fact;
            fact = Math.multiplyExact(fact, i+1);  // error on overflow
        }
        this.count = fact;
    }

    public List<String> permutations() {
        var list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (var n = 0; n < count; n++) {
            var indices = decode(factorial(n));
            list.add(
                IntStream.of(indices).mapToObj(j -> values[j]).collect(joining())
                );
        }
        return list;
    }

    private int[] factorial(int n) {
        var result = new int[len];
        var rest = n;
        for (var i = len-1; rest>0 && i>=0; i--) {
            result[i] = rest / factorials[i];
            rest %= factorials[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int[] decode(int[] factorial) {
        for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            var v = factorial[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (factorial[j] >= v) {
                    factorial[j] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return factorial;
    }
}
```

This can be called like in:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var p = new Permutation("c2","b2","a2");
        p.permutations().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

which should print:

> ```
> a2b2c2
> b2a2c2
> a2c2b2
> c2a2b2
> b2c2a2
> c2b2a2
> ```

---

<sup>**1** - very interesting, thanks for the question!</sup>

Comment: I wonder, did OP mean Java island rather than Java language?